# Genymotion cant connect camera

Tags: android, genymotion

Only dummy camera show on front camera and back camera device like this :
[image: no webcam0]

can anyone help ? thanks

Comment: you have to run it on real device instead.

Comment: i cant find webcam0 in dropdown front camera and back camera

Comment: Does your webcam work with another application like [Cheese](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Cheese)?

Comment: yes, it work properly in cheese webcam

Answer (score 1):

Check the  front or back check box under the Preview section .If your cam diver is perfectly installed than you might see your self on preview